# make: *** No rule to make target - gfortran

Tags: macos, makefile, fortran, gfortran

I am trying to compile a code -
this code uses a few libraries and for starters I am trying to create a makefile to get one library
I am having difficulties.
this is the makefile

```
HOME        = $(shell pwd)
LIBNA       = libbv.a
LIBZP       = $(HOME)/$(LIBNA)

# FFLAGC      = -Mextend -Msave -g -C -Mchkfpstk -Mchkptr -fpic -Ktrap=fp


FC = gfortran
 ifeq ($(OSTYPE),linux)
        FC = pgf95 -Msave -fpic
 endif

# per il gfortran
 FFLAGC      = -g -Wall-ffixed-line-length-0 -Mextend -Msave -g -C -Mchkfpstk -Mchkptr -fpic -Ktrap=fp

# FC = gfortran
#

SOURCE = \
filename1.f\
filename2.f\
...
filenamen.f


.SUFFIXES: .f




OBJ = $(SRCS:.f=.o)

.f.o:
    $(FC) $(FFLAG)   -c   $< $@


$(LIBZP): $(LIBZP)($(OBJ))
    ar -r $(LIBZP) $?
    rm -f $?
```

this is the makefile I am using.
I get the error

> make: *** No rule to make target `absolutepath/libbv.a()', needed by`
>   absolute_path/libbv.a'.  Stop.

I was wondering if any of you can help

Answer (score 3):

Well, your error message shows this:

```
absolutepath/libbv.a()
```

with nothing inside the parentheses.  But your makefile has this:

```
$(LIBZP): $(LIBZP)($(OBJ))
```

with `$(OBJ)` in the parentheses.  So clearly, `$(OBJ)` is expanding to the empty string.  Why is that?

Well, `OBJ` is set here:

```
OBJ = $(SRCS:.f=.o)
```

based on `SRCS`.  Well, what does that variable contain?

Aha.  Nothing, because it's never set.  You set this though:

```
SOURCE = \
    ...
```

`SOURCE` != `SRCS`, so you're modifying an empty variable and `OBJ` is the empty string.

I'm not sure why you're prefixing the target with the current directory... that's where it will go by default if you don't specify any directory.  In any event, you can use `$(CURDIR)` rather than running `$(shell pwd)`.

If you're going to use GNU make anyway, I recommend you use pattern rules rather than suffix rules: they're much simpler to read/understand:

```
%.o : %.f
        $(FC) $(FFLAG) -c $< $@
```

Also don't you need a `-o` here before `$@`?  I don't use Fortran compilers but I would imagine they work more or less the same as C/C++ compilers.